# Chrome console не выводит данные

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(info) {
   alert("s");
   console.log("POCHEMU TI NE RABOTAESH?");
});
```

Есть расширение, в нем есть такой код. Захожу в консоль - пустота.
Алёрт срабатывает постоянно, а вот в консоль ничего не выводит. Почему?

Вот сама консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что у расширения другая консоль. Найди в расширениях ссылку "фоновая страница"

Comment: Ударил себя по лицу, спасибо!